# Unable to Override MaxRecievedMessageSize from Code Behind

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

i hosting A WCF REST serivce and consuming it in same webrole. the Configuration is done in codebehind. i have tried so many solution and post on this,

but i am not able to figure out why i am not able to override the `MaxRecievedMessageSize`  . if size exceeds 64kb. its throws exception.

```
WebChannelFactory<X> channelFactory;

                if (!ChannelFactories.ContainsKey(endpointName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                {
                    channelFactory = new WebChannelFactory<X>(new Uri(endpointName));

                    lock (ChannelFactories.SyncRoot)
                    {
                        ChannelFactories[endpointName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)] = channelFactory;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    channelFactory =
                        ChannelFactories[endpointName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)] as
                        WebChannelFactory<X>;
                }
                //Configure The Size here

                if (channelFactory != null)
                {

                    channelFactory.Endpoint.Binding = new WebHttpBinding
                        {

                            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                            ReaderQuotas =new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                                {
                                    MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                                    MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
                                    MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                                    MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647,
                                    MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647
                                },
                            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
                            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
                            TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
                            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
                            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0)
                        };
```

And Web.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" logMalformedMessages="true" maxMessagesToLog="5000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"></messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
    <standardEndpoints></standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can change the binding on a `WebChannelFactory` after it's created (but I'm not 100% sure on that).  There are very few things you can change once you create a factory.  Most likely it's using the default values for `WebHttpBinding`, so that's why you're getting the lower limit.

Try creating the binding and passing it into one of the `WebChannelFactory<T>` constructor overloads, like this:

```
WebHttpBinding myBinding = new WebHttpBinding
                           {
                               MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                               MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                               ReaderQuotas =new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                               {
                                   MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                                   MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
                                   MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                                   MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647,
                                   MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647
                               },
                               MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                               OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
                               ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
                               TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
                               CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
                               SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0)
                           };

if (!ChannelFactories.ContainsKey(endpointName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
{

    // Pass the binding created above and the URI into the constructor
    channelFactory = new WebChannelFactory<X>(myBinding, new Uri(endpointName));

    lock (ChannelFactories.SyncRoot)
    {
        ChannelFactories[endpointName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)] = channelFactory;
    }
}
else
{
    channelFactory = ChannelFactories[endpointName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)] as WebChannelFactory<X>;
}
```

In the code above, I used the overload of `WebFactoryChannel<T>` that takes a binding and an URI - [`WebChannelFactory<TChannel> Constructor (Binding, Uri)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908550%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).